# Can I use Unity to function as a battle server for my game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to build a battle server with Unity. However, I'm worried about its  efficiency and the way it runs.

- Is it cross-platform?
- Can it stop using the render thread?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for people looking for answers to problems they've attempted to solve but cannot find a solution. It is not for recommendations about tools. You might be more interested in the Game Development site on the Stack Exchange Network, but please be sure to read the site's [tour](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know how to ask a question there.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a Unity application in a "headless" mode by specifying the `-batchmode` command line parameter. As stated [in the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html) this will:

> Run the game in “headless” mode. The game will not display anything or
>   accept user input. This is mostly useful for running servers for
>   networked games.

Cross-platform support should not (necessarily) be an issue, certainly not with the [recently introduced networking components](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNet.html).

As for subsequent usefulness or efficiency, the answer is going to be "try and see".